# How to make a for loop to start from anywhere and end it same position?

Tags: java, android

I am having a array list of integer type , say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.i need to reorder the list with the dynamic index values suppose if i pass the index value as 4 the array should be re ordered as 5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4 .....

Comment: have you tried anything? show us your effort

Comment: Hint: use the % operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't for loop this.. Use `Collections.subList()` instead

```
fun reorder(list: ArrayList<Int>, breakIndex: Int): ArrayList<Int> {
    return (list.subList(breakIndex, list.size) + list.subList(0, breakIndex)) as ArrayList<Int>
}
```

This is in Kotlin but, I guess you get the point. Let me know otherwise.

**Edit:** I can add the Java version for you. Though I haven't used Java for quite some time so this might be uglier than necessary but...

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> reorder(ArrayList<Integer> list, Integer breakIndex) {
    ArrayList<Integer> reorderedList = new ArrayList<>();
    reorderedList.addAll(list.subList(breakIndex, list.size()));
    reorderedList.addAll(list.subList(0, breakIndex));
    return reorderedList;
}
```

Comment: aww it is so simple working so good .. thank you @Algar

Comment: @Sri No worries, I'm glad to help! :) I would appreciate if you mark the answer as correct if you feel that it is :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know Java but here is how I would approach it :

```
public void foo(int index, array arr) {
    int len = arr.length;
    int pos = 0;
    string hs = "";
    for(int i = index+1;i != index;i++) {
        if(i = len-1) {
            i=0
        }
        hs = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[pos];
        pos++;
    }
}
```

I hope this could help you or at least inspire you !

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Integer> originalList;
    int index;

    // init value sample
    originalList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));

    // init value index
    index = 4;

    // reorder array list
    ArrayList<Integer> resultList = reorderListArray(originalList, index);

    Log.v("resultList", "index after reorder: " + resultList.toString());

}

public ArrayList<Integer> reorderListArray(ArrayList<Integer> listArr, int indexValue) {
    ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int indexOrder = 0;
    // case 1
    if (indexValue == listArr.get(0)) return listArr;

    // case 2
    if (indexValue == listArr.get(listArr.size() - 1)) {
        Collections.reverse(listArr);
        return listArr;
    }

    // case 3
    for(int i=0; i < listArr.size(); i++) {
        if(listArr.get(i) == indexValue) {
            indexOrder = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i=indexOrder; i < listArr.size(); i++) {
        resultList.add(listArr.get(i));
    }
    for(int i=0; i < indexOrder; i++) {
        resultList.add(listArr.get(i));
    }
    return resultList;
}
```

You need check condition for params input: [array list] and [dynamic index values].